# What are the "nice" properties of the diamond norm and why is it used?

Tags: fidelity, nisq, diamond-norm

I have heard about the diamond norm, and from what I understood it is a "nice" tool to quantify quality of quantum gates in the NISQ era. I would like to know a little more before going in detail in the litterature.

My question are the following:

Why is it considered as a good tool to quantify quality of quantum gates? Why this tool and not another one?

What are the nice properties this tool has? I have seen in [Is the diamond norm subadditive under composition?](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/7043/is-the-diamond-norm-subadditive-under-composition) that it is subbaditive which make the tool useful to  bound the diamond norm of a full algorithm given the diamond norm of each gate. Are there other some useful properties? I guess this question will be related somehow to the previous one. I tried to find this information in literature, but unfortunately all papers I read just give the definition and the diamond norm and a way to compute it numerically.

Comment: Mark Wilde's textbook might be a good resource to look up these properties. There is a chapter called 'Distance Measures' which discusses this norm. You can access a free pdf at this link : https://arxiv.org/abs/1106.1445

Comment: It is natural in the same way you want CP maps, not just positive maps: You want your map also to work - or your gate quality also be good - if you act on part of a larger quantum system.

Comment: @PurvaThakre thank you for the link, it is really a nice reference !

Comment: @NorbertSchuch allright, I see what you mean. Thanks.